# How can I allow my users to print their forms after submission in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to allow users to print the form either before or after they submit it (beyond printing an email confirmation that includes submission details).

Answer (score 1):

You can include entry details on the confirmation page in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), which will automatically include a read-only printable version of the form submission users can print for their records. Here are the steps to configure this:

1. Go to Build for the form you are working on
2. Click on Submisssion Settings in the green footer or on the Submit button area on your form
3. Click the Include entry details? checkbox under Confirmation Options
4. Save your form

This will make the full entry details appear on the confirmation page for the form.

[image]